# Xaml: < and > in Attributs like: Text="<- vor"

Tags: xaml, attributes, unicode-escapes

I want to write something as that what I wrote in the title in a XAML attribute.
I know I have a book in that it stays but its a really thick book and I dont find it anymore.
Also I cant search it with Google, because it dont accept chars like < , > . ( ) and somemore.
Help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 special characters in XAML:

1. `<`
2. `>`
3. `&`
4. `"`

In order to use any one of these characters in a string literal (such as a `TextBlock`), use the W3C Xaml standard.

For example `<TextBlock Text="&lt;&lt;"/>` will produce a `TextBlock` that displays "<<" in the text field.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I have found another solution as well but that is not so good because it is working based on unicodecodes but yours is better. in addition the > isnt that special because you cam simply use it in attributes.